# How does sort -k 1,2 work?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

Can someone explain what `sort -k 1,1` and `sort -k 1,2` does?

```
$ echo -e "9 3 5\n8 2 6\n7 4 1\n"
9 3 5
8 2 6
7 4 1

$ echo -e "9 3 5\n8 2 6\n7 4 1\n" | sort -k 2 -t " " -i
8 2 6
9 3 5
7 4 1

$ echo -e "9 3 5\n8 2 6\n7 4 1\n" | sort -k 1,1 -t " " -i
7 4 1
8 2 6
9 3 5

$ echo -e "9 3 5\n8 2 6\n7 4 1\n" | sort -k 1,2 -t " " -i
7 4 1
8 2 6
9 3 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from `man sort`:

```
   -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
          start  a  key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of
          line).  See POS syntax below
```

So:

```
-k 2
```

would start at key 2 until the end of the line.

```
-k 1,1
```

would start at key 1 and end at key 1.  Likewise for `-k 1,2`.

---

Your sample input doesn't show the difference, but if you were to modify it slightly then it might be more clear:

```
$ echo -e "9 3 5\n9 2 6\n7 4 1" | sort -k1,1 -t' '
7 4 1
9 2 6
9 3 5
$ echo -e "9 3 5\n9 2 6\n7 4 1" | sort -k1,2 -t' '
7 4 1
9 2 6
9 3 5
$ echo -e "9 3 5\n9 2 6\n7 4 1" | sort -k1,1 -t' ' -s
7 4 1
9 3 5
9 2 6
```

Particularly observe case 1 and 3.  The output in case 1 was affected even when the sort was to be applied to key 1.  Use the `-s` option in order to *stabilize* the sort:

```
   -s, --stable
          stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the --debug option to GNU sort available since version 8.6 (2010-10-15)

```
$ echo -e "9 3 5\n8 2 6\n7 4 1" | sort --debug -k 2 -t " " -i
sort: using `en_US.utf8' sorting rules
8 2 6
___
_____
9 3 5
___
_____
7 4 1
___
_____
$ echo -e "9 3 5\n8 2 6\n7 4 1" | sort --debug -k 1,1 -t " " -i
sort: using `en_US.utf8' sorting rules
7 4 1
_
_____
8 2 6
_
_____
9 3 5
_
_____
$ echo -e "9 3 5\n8 2 6\n7 4 1" | sort --debug -k 1,2 -t " " -i
sort: using `en_US.utf8' sorting rules
7 4 1
___
_____
8 2 6
___
_____
9 3 5
___
_____
```

Note the last **_** in each line showing a second comparison used on the whole line is the sort of last resort and can be suppressed using the -s option